# Transform column with int flags to array of strings in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe with a column called "traits" which is an integer composed of multiple flags.

I need to convert this column to a list of strings (for elastic search indexing). Conversion looks like this.

```
TRAIT_0 = 0
TRAIT_1 = 1
TRAIT_2 = 2
def flag_to_list(flag: int) -> List[str]:
    trait_list = []
    if flag & (1 << TRAIT_0):
        trait_list.append("TRAIT_0")
    elif flag & (1 << TRAIT_1):
        trait_list.append("TRAIT_1")
    elif flag & (1 << TRAIT_2):
        trait_list.append("TRAIT_2")

    return trait_list
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this transformation in pyspark? I saw lots of examples on how to do concatenation and splitting of strings, but not an operation like this.

Using pyspark vesion 2.4.5

Input json looks like this:
`{ "name": "John Doe", "traits": 5 }`
Output json should look like this:
`{ "name": "John Doe", "traits": ["TRAIT_0", "TRAIT_2"] }`

Comment: It would help if you could provide sample reproducible data and required output. Also what is your spark version ?

Comment: Edited my question, pyspark version is 2.4.5 and provided input and output data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try SparkSQL built-in functions: (1) use [conv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#conv) + [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#split) to convert integer(base-10) -> binary(base-2) -> string -> array of strings(reversed), (2) based on `0` or `1` values and their array indices to [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#filter) and [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/sql/index.html#transform) the array into the corresponding array of named traits:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame([("name1", 5),("name2", 1),("name3", 0),("name4", 12)], ['name', 'traits'])
#DataFrame[name: string, traits: bigint]

traits = [ "Traits_{}".format(i) for i in range(8) ]
traits_array = "array({})".format(",".join("'{}'".format(e) for e in traits))
# array('Traits_0','Traits_1','Traits_2','Traits_3','Traits_4','Traits_5','Traits_6','Traits_7')

sql_expr = """

    filter(
      transform(
        /* convert int -> binary -> string -> array of strings, and then reverse the array */
        reverse(split(string(conv(traits,10,2)),'(?!$)')),
        /* take the corresponding items from the traits_array when value > 0, else NULL */
        (x,i) -> {}[IF(x='1',i,NULL)]
      ),
      /* filter out NULL items from the array */
      y -> y is not NULL
    ) AS trait_list

""".format(traits_array)
# filter(
#   transform(
#     reverse(split(string(conv(traits,10,2)),'(?!$)')),
#     (x,i) -> array('Traits_0','Traits_1','Traits_2','Traits_3','Traits_4','Traits_5','Traits_6','Traits_7')[IF(x='1',i,NULL)]
#   ),
#   y -> y is not NULL
# )

df.withColumn("traits_list", expr(sql_expr)).show(truncate=False)
+-----+------+--------------------+
|name |traits|traits_list         |
+-----+------+--------------------+
|name1|5     |[Traits_0, Traits_2]|
|name2|1     |[Traits_0]          |
|name3|0     |[]                  |
|name4|12    |[Traits_2, Traits_3]|
+-----+------+--------------------+
```

Below is the result after running `reverse(split(string(conv(traits,10,2)),'(?!$)'))`, notice that the split-pattern `(?!$)` is used to avoid a NULL shown as the last array item.

```
df.selectExpr("*", "reverse(split(string(conv(traits,10,2)),'(?!$)')) as t1").show()
+-----+------+------------+
| name|traits|          t1|
+-----+------+------------+
|name1|     5|   [1, 0, 1]|
|name2|     1|         [1]|
|name3|     0|         [0]|
|name4|    12|[0, 0, 1, 1]|
+-----+------+------------+
```

Comment: Marking this one as the correct answer since using SparkSql functions is more performant than the UDF-based approach, even though this one is a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

We can define a UDF to wrap your function and then call it. This is some sample code:

```py
from typing import List
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

TRAIT_0 = 0
TRAIT_1 = 1
TRAIT_2 = 2


def flag_to_list(flag: int) -> List[str]:
    trait_list = []
    if flag & (1 << TRAIT_0):
        trait_list.append("TRAIT_0")
    elif flag & (1 << TRAIT_1):
        trait_list.append("TRAIT_1")
    elif flag & (1 << TRAIT_2):
        trait_list.append("TRAIT_2")
    return trait_list


flag_to_list_udf = udf(lambda x: None if x is None else flag_to_list(x),
                       ArrayType(StringType()))

# Create dummy data to test
data = [
    { "name": "John Doe", "traits": 5 },
    { "name": "Jane Doe", "traits": 2 },
    { "name": "Jane Roe", "traits": 0 },
    { "name": "John Roe", "traits": 6 },
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, 'name STRING, traits INT')
df.show()
# +--------+------+
# |    name|traits|
# +--------+------+
# |John Doe|     5|
# |Jane Doe|     2|
# |Jane Roe|     0|
# |John Roe|     6|
# +--------+------+

df = df.withColumn('traits_processed', flag_to_list_udf(df['traits']))
df.show()
# +--------+------+----------------+
# |    name|traits|traits_processed|
# +--------+------+----------------+
# |John Doe|     5|       [TRAIT_0]|
# |Jane Doe|     2|       [TRAIT_1]|
# |Jane Roe|     0|              []|
# |John Roe|     6|       [TRAIT_1]|
# +--------+------+----------------+
```

If you don't want to create a new column, you can replace `traits_processed` with `traits`.